# ocfs2 on oracle linux

Tags: linux, ocfs2

Ive tried on Fedora, got stuck. Downloaded oracle linux.

- 3 virtual machines: ocfs2-1, ocfs2-2, ocfs2-3 (all: 2x NIC, 1xbridge, 1xinternal network - for ocfs2)
- on ocfs2-1 I've created additional disk (fixed size) for storage and I've done "`VboxManage modifyhd UUID -type shareable`" for this disk
  -on others machines I've created disk too but with "Choose Existing Disk" option
- I've configured every "internal network" interface on each machine as static in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`:
  -`ocfs2-1 10.0.0.1`;
      `ocfs2-2 10.0.0.2`;
     `ocfs2-3 10.0.0.3`
- I've installed ocfs2 tools with "`yum install ocfs2-tools.x86_64`"
- On each machine I've done:

:

```
o2cb add-cluster ocfs2demo
o2cb add-node --ip 10.0.0.1 --port 7777 --number 1 ocfs2demo ocfs2-1
o2cb add-node --ip 10.0.0.2 --port 7777 --number 2 ocfs2demo ocfs2-2
o2cb add-node --ip 10.0.0.3 --port 7777 --number 3 ocfs2demo ocfs2-3
```

When I tried to register-cluster with "`o2cb register-cluster ocfs2demo`", I got an error: "**02cb: Unable to access cluster service while trying initialize cluster**"
When in "`/etc/init.d/`" I ran "`./o2cb load`", I was able to make register-cluster statement but after  that, when I tried: "`sudo o2cb start-heartbeat ocfs2demo`" I got an error: "**o2cb: Cluster 'ocfs2demo' not registered**"
- `/etc/ocfs2/cluster.conf` is the same on all nodes
- kernel modules for ocfs2 are in good directory:
     -"`find / -name "*ocfs2_nodemanager*" -print`" in 
      /lib/modules/`uname-r`/kernel/fs/ocfs2
- Maybe driver installed doesn't match the version of my kernel ?:
Kernel (uname -r): 3.8.13-55.1.6
Driver (rpm -qa|grep ocfs2): ocfs2-tools-1.8.0-16
- service o2cb status:

```
Driver for "configfs": Loaded
Filesystem "configfs": Mounted
Stack glue driver: Loaded
Stack plugin "o2cb": Loaded
Driver for "ocfs2_dlmfs": Loaded
Filesystem :ocfs2_dlmfs": Mounted
Checking o2cb cluster "ocfs2demo": Offline
```

- I ran "`sudo systemctl enable o2cb.service`" - to enable o2cb
- After last command, cluster is still "Offline"
- I tried: "`/etc/init.d/o2cb force-reload`" - nothing has changed

I have no idea what else I can try to start this thing. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

You did not mention whether you copied the cluster.conf file to each node. What you have shown does not fit any of the install guides. After creating the cluster.conf, you copy it to all nodes under `/etc/ocfs2/cluster.conf`, then run  `service o2cb configure` on all the nodes.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_instcfg_ocfs2.html#ol_prepare_ocfs2